# Duplicate local variable n

Tags: java

I have been trying to solve a problem in java, and tried searching for answers. 
I couldn't find anything other than the fact I might have declared a variable twice, which I don't see where.

I'm trying to get the user input, an integer "n", for the starting number of bottles. 
Please help and tell me how to change and fix this.

Here's the section of my code:

```
public class BottlesOfBeer {

    private static Scanner bottles;
    public static void number(int n) {
        bottles = new Scanner(System. in );
        bottles.useDelimiter("\n");

        System.out.println("Enter the starting number of " + "bottles in the song " + "'99 Bottles of Beer on the Wall':");
        int n = bottles.nextInt();

        if (n > 1) {
            System.out.print(n + " bottles of beer on the wall, " + n + " bottles of beer, ya' take one down, " +
                "ya' pass it around, ");
            n = n - 1;
            System.out.println(n + " bottles of beer on the wall.");
            number(n);
        } else {

            if (n == 1) {
                System.out.print(n + " bottle of beer on the wall, " + n + " bottle of beer, ya' take one down, " +
                    "ya' pass it around, ");
                n = n - 1;
                System.out.println(n + " bottles of beer on the wall.");
                number(n);
            } else {
                System.out.println("No more bottles of beer on the wall, " +
                    "no bottles of beer, ya' can't take one down, " + "ya' can't pass it around, 'cause there are" + " no more bottles of beer on the wall!");
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have both the argument `n` in the signature of your `number` method and the variable `n` defined inside the mothod. Since the compiler has no way to tell the two apart, you must rename one of them.

```
public static void number(int n) { // first n
    bottles = new Scanner(System.in);
    bottles.useDelimiter("\n");

        System.out.println("Enter the starting number of " 
                + "bottles in the song "
                + "'99 Bottles of Beer on the Wall':");
        int n = bottles.nextInt(); // second n
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that I already declared n in the parameter. I deleted the second declaration of n and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is not allowed to declare more than one variable with the same name in the same scope. In your code, you have declared a variable named 'n' twice in the method called number. Since these two variables are in the same method scope, compiler can not decide which variable you are referring to when ever you try to refer the variable 'n'.

Note that more than one variable with the same name can be declared as long as they are in different scopes. For example, the following is allowed...

```
public class VariableScope {
    int scopedVar = 10; // First declaration
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            int scopedVar = 200; // Second declaration. 
                                 // This is perfectly valid. But it overrides the first declaration.

    }
}
```